# Linq (or SQL): Get a search query and sort it order by best result

Tags: c#, .net, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to create a search page for my website. The logic is the user enters some keywords and I should search those words then sort the result by best matches.
i.e:
The user enters: "MVC Microsoft WPF ASP.Net".
I want to show those results which contain most matches, such as:

***Best Matches:***

Learning Microsoft ASP.Net MVC
How to host a WPF form in Microsoft ASP.Net

***Partial matches:***

Microsoft MVC
Microsoft WPF
Microsoft ASP.Net
ASP.Net MVC

***Keyword Matches:***

MVC
Microsoft
WPF
ASP.Net

Comment: Can you post some code / the issue you're having?

Comment: What database server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the actual solution.

That's "FullText Index".

A complete tutorial is here:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/

Answer (score 2):

Try out [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/), it sorts search results by relevance by default

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what / how you are searching, a simple solution is to build your website so it is fully indexed on Google and take advantage of [Google Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic strategy; it would require a stored proc:

1. Split your keyword string on spaces, and pad with '%'s.
2. For each search term, perform an insert-select to the same in-memory temp table. You'll get duplicate rows, one per record per "hit" on a search term.
3. Select from this temp table each distinct result, with a count of the number of times that result appears in the temp table. This is your "relevance", by which you can sort.

Comment: This idea is good but I don't know how to count the number of each unique result, do you have any idea?

Comment: using a Group By function would work.  For example `SELECT result, Count(result) FROM #MyTempTable GroupBy result;`